# rails ActiveRecord join tables cascading belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

given the following simple associations, and a selected_company, is my query correctly written to get all documents in the selected company ?

```
    class Document < ActiveRecord::Base      
      belongs_to :user
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :company
      has_many :documents
    end

    class Company < ActiveRecord::Base  
      has_many :users
    end

=== Query
    selected_company: Company.first
    documents_in_selected_company = Document.joins(:User).joins(:User => :Company).where(:company_id => selected_company[:id)
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

just 2 small fixes , association names should be lowercase ... and the where should contains a query string :

```
    documents_in_selected_company = Document.joins(:user).joins(:user => :company).where("companies.id = ?", company.id)
```